# Stylesheets not loading on ie11 or firefox

Tags: css, firefox, internet-explorer-11, stylesheet

Where am I going wrong please guys, tried a lot of variations from various sources, but to no avail - Here is the code, I hope you can help as going slightly bonkers - thanks in advance guys...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Home</title>


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.jpg">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.jpg">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.jpg">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/custom-animations.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Troubleshooting / debugging questions (why isn't this code working) usually aren't good questions for stackoverflow unless you can provide and example that reproduces the problem. See here.. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve With that said. Your syntax seems fine. Need more info.

Comment: I'm assuming your have more to your page? Have you tried creating another test page with the content your provide above and nothing in your <body>? Could help isolate if its something else in your code

Answer (score 0):

First: I would try adding an additional forward-slash before your CSS paths, e.g.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/custom-animations.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css" />`

If that doesn't work, then try testing the absolute paths in place of the relative ones, e.g.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.daveswebsite.com/assets/css/custom-animations.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.daveswebsite.com/assets/css/style.css" />`

If the latter still doesn't work, then there could be a problem with the formatting of your CSS file(s).